# Creating new pandas dataframe based on another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**EDIT:**

**There is a bug in pandas 1.0.5, after upgrading  to 1.1.1, there is no error.**

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like that:

```
   Name      Date      Price      Label   Y      Z
   foo1     1/1/20      100       1       _      _
   foo1     1/1/20      200       2       _      _
    .       .           .         .       .      .
    .       .           .         .       .      .
   foo1     1/8/20      240       1       _      _
   foo2     1/2/20      500       1       _      _
    .       .           .         .       .      .
    .       .           .         .       .      .
   foo2     1/7/20      423       4       _      _
    .       .           .         .       .      .
    .       .           .         .       .      .
```

- There are 80 unique values for the `Name` column, i.e. foo1 - foo80
- There are 20 unique `Date` values
- There are 4 unique `Label` values
- Y and Z columns are irrelevant for the new dataframe

I want to create a table s.t it will has 80 rows(each for each Name), and 20*4 + 1 columns (20x4 for each Date-Label combination, and 1 for the Name).

The final dataframe should look as follows:

```
**Name 1/1/20(Label1)  1/1/20(Label2)  1/1/20(Label3)  1/1/20(Label4)  1/2/20(Label1)    ...    4/7/20(Label4)**
 foo1    100             200              300             -1              -1                        -1
 foo2    -1               -1               -1             -1              500                       -1
...............
...............
```

-1 indicates that there is not entry in the original entry for the specific Name-Date-Label combination.

I'm basically new to pandas, and I can certainly build the dataframe iteratively by hand(if..else solution) but I believe that there is a faster, readable, and easier solution.

```
> df.columns
Index(['A', 'B', 'Date', 'C',
   'D', 'Price', 'Label', 'E',
   'Name', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I',
   'J'],
  dtype='object')

> df.head(10).to_dict('list')

{'A': [160, 457, 457, 482, 482, 482, 482, 423, 223, 506],
'B': ['8/27/2015 0:00',
'10/15/2015 0:00',
'10/15/2015 0:00',
'10/28/2015 0:00',
'10/28/2015 0:00',
'10/28/2015 0:00',
'10/28/2015 0:00',
'9/29/2015 0:00',
'9/9/2015 0:00',
'11/9/2015 0:00'],
'Date': ['8/28/2015 0:00',
'10/16/2015 0:00',
'10/16/2015 0:00',
'10/29/2015 0:00',
'10/29/2015 0:00',
'10/29/2015 0:00',
'10/29/2015 0:00',
'9/30/2015 0:00',
'9/10/2015 0:00',
'11/10/2015 0:00'],
'C': [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
'D': [1271, 1825, 1825, 1455, 1455, 1455, 1455, 2522, 1385, 1765],
'Price': [1058, 1685, 1615, 1195, 1255, 1279, 1295, 2285, 1285, 1665],
'Label': [3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 4],
'E': [13, 127, 127, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
'Name': ['foo1',
'foo2',
'foo2',
'foo3',
'foo3',
'foo3',
'foo3',
'foo4',
'foo4',
'foo3'],
'F': [4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
'G': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
'H': ['Friday',
'Friday',
'Friday',
'Thursday',
'Thursday',
'Thursday',
'Thursday',
'Wednesday',
'Thursday',
'Tuesday'],
'I': [213, 140, 210, 260, 200, 176, 160, 237, 100, 100],
'J': [16.758457907159716,
7.671232876712329,
11.506849315068493,
17.869415807560138,
13.745704467353955,
12.096219931271474,
10.996563573883162,
9.397303727200637,
7.220216606498194,
5.6657223796034]}
```

Using

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame({
    # 'A': [160, 457, 457, 482, 482, 482, 482, 423, 223, 506],
    # 'B': ['8/27/2015 0:00','10/15/2015 0:00','10/15/2015 0:00','10/28/2015 0:00','10/28/2015 0:00','10/28/2015 0:00','10/28/2015 0:00','9/29/2015 0:00','9/9/2015 0:00','11/9/2015 0:00'],
    'Date': ['8/28/2015 0:00','10/16/2015 0:00','10/16/2015 0:00','10/29/2015 0:00','10/29/2015 0:00','10/29/2015 0:00','10/29/2015 0:00','9/30/2015 0:00','9/10/2015 0:00','11/10/2015 0:00'],
    # 'C': [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
    # 'D': [1271, 1825, 1825, 1455, 1455, 1455, 1455, 2522, 1385, 1765],
    'Price': [1058, 1685, 1615, 1195, 1255, 1279, 1295, 2285, 1285, 1665],
    'Label': [3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 4],
    # 'E': [13, 127, 127, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
    'Name': ['foo1','foo2','foo2','foo3','foo3','foo3','foo3','foo4','foo4','foo3'],
    # 'F': [4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    # 'G': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    # 'H': ['Friday','Friday','Friday','Thursday','Thursday','Thursday','Thursday','Wednesday','Thursday','Tuesday'],
    # 'I': [213, 140, 210, 260, 200, 176, 160, 237, 100, 100],
    # 'J': [16.758457907159716,7.671232876712329,11.506849315068493,17.869415807560138,13.745704467353955,12.096219931271474,10.996563573883162,9.397303727200637,7.220216606498194,5.6657223796034]
})
df.pivot(index='Name', columns=['Date', 'Label'], values='Price')`
```

I get

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py in _get_level_number(self, level)
   1294         try:
-> 1295             level = self.names.index(level)
   1296         except ValueError:

ValueError: 'Date' is not in list

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-542e5c02777d> in <module>
----> 1 df.pivot(index='Name', columns=['Date', 'Label'], values='Price')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in pivot(self, index, columns, values)
   5921         from pandas.core.reshape.pivot import pivot
   5922 
-> 5923         return pivot(self, index=index, columns=columns, values=values)
   5924 
   5925     _shared_docs[

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py in pivot(data, index, columns, values)
    448         else:
    449             indexed = data._constructor_sliced(data[values].values, index=index)
--> 450     return indexed.unstack(columns)
    451 
    452 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in unstack(self, level, fill_value)
   3548         from pandas.core.reshape.reshape import unstack
   3549 
-> 3550         return unstack(self, level, fill_value)
   3551 
   3552     # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py in unstack(obj, level, fill_value)
    396             # _unstack_multiple only handles MultiIndexes,
    397             # and isn't needed for a single level
--> 398             return _unstack_multiple(obj, level, fill_value=fill_value)
    399         else:
    400             level = level[0]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py in _unstack_multiple(data, clocs, fill_value)
    318     index = data.index
    319 
--> 320     clocs = [index._get_level_number(i) for i in clocs]
    321 
    322     rlocs = [i for i in range(index.nlevels) if i not in clocs]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    318     index = data.index
    319 
--> 320     clocs = [index._get_level_number(i) for i in clocs]
    321 
    322     rlocs = [i for i in range(index.nlevels) if i not in clocs]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py in _get_level_number(self, level)
   1296         except ValueError:
   1297             if not is_integer(level):
-> 1298                 raise KeyError(f"Level {level} not found")
   1299             elif level < 0:
   1300                 level += self.nlevels

KeyError: 'Level Date not found'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pivot a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)

Comment: what `pd.__version__` are you using? this looks like a bug

Comment: Using Version 1.0.5, should I 'conda update pandas'?

Comment: Upgraded to 1.1.1, It works now! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `df.pivot`

```
df = df.pivot(index='Name', columns=['Date', 'Label'], values='Price')
```

Warning: if any name-date-label combination is duplicated (i.e. appears in more than one row) then an error will be raised. Use `pivot_table` or better `groupby` + `unstack`

If `Name`, `Date`, and `Label` are in the index then use `unstack` instead of `pivot`

---

Update with sample data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    # 'A': [160, 457, 457, 482, 482, 482, 482, 423, 223, 506],
    # 'B': ['8/27/2015 0:00','10/15/2015 0:00','10/15/2015 0:00','10/28/2015 0:00','10/28/2015 0:00','10/28/2015 0:00','10/28/2015 0:00','9/29/2015 0:00','9/9/2015 0:00','11/9/2015 0:00'],
    'Date': ['8/28/2015 0:00','10/16/2015 0:00','10/16/2015 0:00','10/29/2015 0:00','10/29/2015 0:00','10/29/2015 0:00','10/29/2015 0:00','9/30/2015 0:00','9/10/2015 0:00','11/10/2015 0:00'],
    # 'C': [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
    # 'D': [1271, 1825, 1825, 1455, 1455, 1455, 1455, 2522, 1385, 1765],
    'Price': [1058, 1685, 1615, 1195, 1255, 1279, 1295, 2285, 1285, 1665],
    'Label': [3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 4],
    # 'E': [13, 127, 127, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
    'Name': ['foo1','foo2','foo2','foo3','foo3','foo3','foo3','foo4','foo4','foo3'],
    # 'F': [4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    # 'G': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    # 'H': ['Friday','Friday','Friday','Thursday','Thursday','Thursday','Thursday','Wednesday','Thursday','Tuesday'],
    # 'I': [213, 140, 210, 260, 200, 176, 160, 237, 100, 100],
    # 'J': [16.758457907159716,7.671232876712329,11.506849315068493,17.869415807560138,13.745704467353955,12.096219931271474,10.996563573883162,9.397303727200637,7.220216606498194,5.6657223796034]
})
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df = df.pivot(index='Name', columns=['Date', 'Label'], values='Price')
df = df.fillna(-1)
print(df)
```

Output

```
Date  2015-08-28 2015-10-16         2015-10-29  ...         2015-09-30 2015-09-10 2015-11-10
Label          3          3       2          1  ...       2          2          1          4
Name                                            ...
foo1      1058.0        NaN     NaN        NaN  ...     NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
foo2         NaN     1685.0  1615.0        NaN  ...     NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
foo3         NaN        NaN     NaN     1195.0  ...  1295.0        NaN        NaN     1665.0
foo4         NaN        NaN     NaN        NaN  ...     NaN     2285.0     1285.0        NaN

[4 rows x 10 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a deeper look at pivoting. Regarding your answer, I get "ValueError: 'Date' is not in list". Neither of the columns are in the index.

Comment: Done, guess they are in the Index? Sorry, I miss interpreted the meaning of Index. told ya, I'm new to pandas :D

Comment: pandas dataframes have indices in rows and columns, what we normally refer to as "Index" is really "row index"

Comment: Added required information, btw, there is no name-date-label duplication, the df was cleaned of those. Thanks!

Comment: Using exactly your solution, on a plain Jupyter notebook, I get: "ValueError: 'Date' is not in list" again.

Comment: @PhilipL Hmm.. Does this line of code working `df.pivot(index='Name', columns=['Date', 'Label'], values='Price')`?

Comment: @PhilipL please edit your question and show the full traceback

Comment: Added full traceback.